# Recover data from Simple Volume

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt, partition-recovery

I have a 1TB partitioned into two.

```
Windows - Simple Volume(can't access)
Ubuntu  - ext4 (works)
```

I can't access the Windows partition because it is a simple volume. I haven't formatted the disk, so I know that my data is still present. How do I get back the data?

Here is a description of the full detail of events.

[image]

Comment: Have you done something before it happened? (Windows Update, etc)

Comment: I wanted to extend my Windows partition to its original size(1TB), so on the other partition, I deleted the Ubuntu that I had before and tried to extend the space from Windows. I had to convert to a Simple Volume to do that, and when I did, I couldn't get into that now free space (deleted Ubuntu partition).

Comment: You can't access the Windows partition from where?  Ubuntu or Windows?  What does "I couldn't get into that now free space" mean?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from the disk management console?

Comment: @psusi I can't access the partition from both Ubuntu and Windows. Previously, I deleted my (old) Ubuntu partition so I could extend the space of Windows to the "original" size of the hard disk as if it were a new laptop. Now I couldn't extend the Windows partition into the empty open space partition (which previously had my Ubuntu) because I got a message similar to [this](https://www.partitionwizard.com/images/tu518/not-enough-space-available-on-the-disk-to-complete-this-operation-2.jpg).

Comment: @DennisJohnson The disk management console doesn't say [much about my disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCHIr.png), so I added [another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NQJO.png) so you can get a better idea.

Comment: The 3 screen shots you posted present 3 completely different disk/partition configurations.  What gives?  The last one doesn't show there being any free space.

Comment: @psusi The first image is from the disk management console from  Windows. The second screenshot is from the Mini Partition Tool, so it can "see" the hidden partitions that Windows can't see. Please ignore Disk 3, it's my flash drive. The most important thing to check is Disk 1 and "Dynamic Disk"/Disk 2.

Comment: The first screen shot shows the free space on disk 2, following the O: drive.  The second screen shot shows there is no disk 2 at all.  The third screen shot shows no free space on disk 2.  Instead it shows a FAT32 partition and another NTFS partition.  In addition, the first screen shot shows only one NTFS partition that is 899 gb, and the third claims it is only 687gb.  None of this makes any sense at all.

Comment: @psusi Please read [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0u9D.png). I hope this will explain everything.

Comment: Ubuntu does not use a FAT32 partition for booting, so that appears to just be useless junk.  Since you tried to extend the NTFS partition into the free space on the far side of the FAT32 partition ( should have deleted that instead ), Windows had to convert it to an advanced disk / spanned volume to grow it.  That seems to have worked, but when you booted Ubuntu and formatted half of it, you wreaked your filesystem.  At this point it's restore from backup time.

Comment: @psusi I don't have a backup, that's why I would like to know how to get my data out since it is still on the drive.

Comment: You don't.  This is why you need to keep backups of data you do not want to lose.

Comment: Honestly @psusi, I would have preferred a solution, but it's okay, I will keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to download [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) and make sure that I run it in Windows.
Now, all I had to do was to analyze the disk, and figure out which one was my 638GB, which had my lost data. Afterward, change it to a Primary Disk, and reboot.

My data disk(rather partition) showed with no errors.